# How can we destroy the View from inside the view?

Tags: android

I have a Custom View which has a button clicking on which would destroy the Custom View. I want the logic of the destruction inside the View only so that I can dynamically add the View anywhere without writing the its destruction code in its parent. So I came up with the following code

```
  this.removeAllViews();
  ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).removeView(this);
```

Is this the correct way, or is there some more elegent way of destroying the view ?

Comment: To me this question is useful and clear, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks legit to me. That's the point where I would release resources also.

To be sure the layout is still around, I would also check for nullity on `getParent()`:

```
this.removeAllViews();
if (this.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).removeView(this);
}
```

Of course you should not hold references to this view inside other classes, say `Activity` of `Fragment`, because then view might get destroyed or, worse, just removed from the layout, without you even knowing.

If you really need some reference to your `RemovableView` inside other classes then you should implement some sort of interface as per the other answer. But in my opinion the code could stay the same, inside the custom view:

```
public class RemovableView {

    private void remove() {

        this.removeAllViews();
        if (this.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).removeView(this);
        }

        activity.onViewRemoved();
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Activity implements MyCallback {

    private RemovableView view; 

    @Override
    public void onViewRemoved() {
        //do what you need to do, if any.
        }
}
```

This could fit your needs, as destroy code stays inside the view class, and you only implement the interface if you really need to. I believe there's no need to call `viewGroup.removeView(view)` from the Activity, since it is the exact same method called on the same object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MD why? OP asked "is this correct?" and I am telling "Yes, in my opinion; I see no better way". This is the best contribution I can give, yet a contribution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the logic of the destruction inside the View

This is wrong approach if you ask me. View/Fragment is just part of bigger picture managed by either i.e. parent Activity or parent Fragment etc and usually got no idea about other elements or relationships. So if element needs to be gone, it should tell its parent to be removed therefore your parent/host should expose interface your child should use to ask for the removal.

Comment: Isn't exactly what the OP is doing by calling `getParent()`? I mean, what is the difference between calling  `getParent().removeView(this)` and  `viewGroup.removeView(view)` exactly?

Comment: No. He gets parent structures and plays with it himself, while it should be telling parent to do that instead.

Comment: I don't see any difference in this case. It's the same method called from two different classes.

Comment: Narrow thinking. Your parent may i.e. keep some dependencies, state etc and so if you mess with this and take anything out parent expects to still be present you will most likely end with crash sooner or later. If parent set all things up, parent should clean/remove it because only parent may know how to do that right way. Your child objects shall only ask for certain operations to be done.

Comment: Hi @MarcinOrlowski, I can understand that it is ethically wrong for a child view to destroy itself without informing its parent , but in my case , the child view is using the parent only to get presented to the current screen, so in a way it is attaching itself to the latest current layout, and hence can have many different kinds of parents. So it would be good if I dont have to write its destruction code everywhere. So I am asking about a way to destroy it from inside its View.